# Chainlink node operator set Link Fee

Tags: oracle, smartcontracts, chainlink

I've setup a chainlink node running on AWS. V 1.0.1.

I am able to call jobs on the node and return data, but all fees for everyjob I setup are 1 LINK.  I cannot find the location to change this fee.  Can someone help me find where this fee is setup?

Answer (score 2):

To change the fee for a specific job, add this to the job's toml file:

`minContractPaymentLinkJuels = <fee>`

To set up fee on node globally, add the following line to the node's .env file:

`MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS = <fee>`

Replacing `<fee>` for your desired minimum payment in JUELS.

JUELS are equivalent to WEI in Ethereum where 1 Link = 1000000000000000000 JUELS.

Reference: [Chainlink Official Docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables/#minimum_contract_payment_link_juels)

Comment: When I do that and create job, the line seems to disappear on job creation. I was able to put the same line in my node config and it worked, but now it's only globally set.