# Is there a way to set the LINK fee to 0 as a node operator?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I'm looking to run a production node that checks a database to see whether or not an address is available to redeem an incentive token, but I don't want them to have to pay LINK in order to make this check.
How do I change the fee so that the only thing users have to pay to call the 'check' function is gas for the transaction??

Comment: This is also answered in this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71403949/chainlink-node-operator-set-link-fee/71471865#71471865)

Comment: It's possible in a way already answered, just the thing is that your node won't be profitable (if you're fine with that).

Answer (score 2):

To set the fee for a job-spec equal to 0, add the following code into the `.toml` job-spec.

```
minContractPaymentLinkJuels = 0
```

If you would like to set all job-specs equal to 0 at the node level, add the following code into the chainlink `.env` file.

```
MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS = 0
```

https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables/#minimum_contract_payment_link_juels

Comment: Just a note that jobs that use `ethTx` tasks have a minimum payment amount as those write transactions to the blockchain that update state. it is in the docs referred to above.